# How to send received sms to sqlite database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Am developing an android application, where i need to store the received incoming message in sqlite database. I need to store the particular message format in database. now my application is receiving particular message format but i need to push those messages to database. Please help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

mainactivity.java:

```
public class SecureMessagesActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener
{
    Button btnSent, btninbox, btndraft;
    TextView tv_msg, tv_no;
    ListView lvmsg;
    SmsReceiver sms;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //setTheme( android.R.style.Theme_Light );
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btninbox = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInbox );
        btninbox.setOnClickListener(this);

        lvmsg = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMsg);
    }
ArrayList<String> sms1 = new ArrayList<String>();


    public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id ) 
    {
        try 
        {
            //Retriving Lat Lan from msg body
                String[] splitted = sms1.get( pos ).split("\n"); 
            String sender = splitted[0];

            String data= splitted[1];
            String[] latval=data.split(":");
            String lat=latval[1];//Lat Value 

            String data1 = splitted[2];
            String[] lanval=data1.split(":");
            String lan=lanval[1];//Lan Value

            Toast.makeText( this, lat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            Toast.makeText( this, lan, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onClick( View v ) 
    {

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query( Uri.parse( "content://sms/inbox" ), null, null, null, null);
        //Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),new String[]{phoneLookUp.DISPLAY_NAME}, condition, null, null, null);
        int indexBody = cursor.getColumnIndex( SmsReceiver.BODY );
        int indexAddr = cursor.getColumnIndex( SmsReceiver.ADDRESS );
        //int indexDate = cursor.getColumnIndex( SmsReceiver.DATE );

        if ( indexBody < 0 || !cursor.moveToFirst() ) return;

        sms1.clear();
        while( cursor.moveToNext() ){
        String str = getContactName(getApplicationContext(),cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SmsReceiver.ADDRESS)))+":"
                    + cursor.getString( indexAddr ) + "\n" 
                    + cursor.getString( indexBody );

        if(str.startsWith("Lat:")|| str.contains("Lat:"))
        {
             sms1.add( str );   
        }







        ListView smsListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.lvMsg );
        smsListView.setAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sms1) );
        smsListView.setOnItemClickListener( this );
        }
        }   
public String getContactName(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri,
                new String[] { PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String contactName = null;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            contactName = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return contactName;
    }

}
```

smsreciver.java:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{


    public static final String SMS_EXTRA_NAME = "pdus";
    public static final String SMS_URI = "content://sms";

    public static final String ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String PERSON = "person";
    public static final String DATE = "date";
    public static final String READ = "read";
    public static final String STATUS = "status";
    public static final String TYPE = "type";
    public static final String BODY = "body";
    public static final String SEEN = "seen";
    public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT = 2;

    public static final int MESSAGE_IS_NOT_READ = 0;
    public static final int MESSAGE_IS_READ = 1;

    public static final int MESSAGE_IS_NOT_SEEN = 0;
    public static final int MESSAGE_IS_SEEN = 1;

    // Change the password here or give a user possibility to change it
   // public static final byte[] PASSWORD = new byte[]{ 0x20, 0x32, 0x34, 0x47, (byte) 0x84, 0x33, 0x58 };
    @Override
    public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) 
    {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String messages = "";
        if (bundle != null)
        {
        //—retrieve the SMS message received—
        Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[smsExtra.length];

        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
        {
        SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsExtra[i]);
        //take out content from sms

        if(sms.getMessageBody().contains("Lat:"))
        {
        String body = sms.getMessageBody().toString();
        String address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();
        messages += "SMS from" + address + ":\n";
        messages += body + "\n";
        //—display the new SMS message—
        Toast.makeText(context, messages, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //MessageBody();
        putSmsToDatabase(sms, context );
        abortBroadcast();
        }
        }
        }

    }


private void putSmsToDatabase( SmsMessage sms, Context context )
{
DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);

SQLiteDatabase db = dataBaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
// Create SMS row
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

values.put(ADDRESS, sms.getOriginatingAddress().toString() );
values.put(DATE, mydate);
values.put(BODY, sms.getMessageBody().toString());
 //values.put( READ, MESSAGE_IS_NOT_READ );
 //values.put( STATUS, sms.getStatus() );
 //values.put( TYPE, MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX );
 //values.put( SEEN, MESSAGE_IS_NOT_SEEN );

db.insert(SMS_URI, null, values);

db.close();

}
}
```

databasehelper.java:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //private static String DB_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/My Files/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/org.secure.sms/database";

    //public static final String SMS_URI = "/data/data/org.secure.sms/databases/";
    public static final String  DATABASE_FILE_PATH= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/data/data/org.secure.sms/databases/";
//  SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/sdcard/sms.db", SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
      //public static final String  DATABASE_NAME      = "mydb"; 
    public static final String db_name = "sms.db";
    public static final int version =1;
    public DB_Path dbp= new DB_Path();
    public SQLiteDatabase db=dbp.getOrders();
    Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("select * from datatable", null);
    Context context;
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, db_name, null, version);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context =context;
    }

    //@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    db.execSQL("create table datatable(address varchar(10), body varchar(30))");
    Toast.makeText(context, "database created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i("dbcreate", "DATABASE HAS CREATED");
    }

    public boolean checkDataBase(String db) {

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
    String myPath = "data/data/"+ context.getPackageName() +"/databases/sms.db" + db;
    checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

    // database does’t exist yet.

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    if (checkDB != null) {

    checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (oldVersion >= newVersion)
    return;

    if (oldVersion == 1) 
    {
    Log.d("New Version", "Datas can be upgraded");
    }

    Log.d("Sample Data", "onUpgrade : " + newVersion);
    }
public class DB_Path{
    public final SQLiteDatabase getOrders(){
        File dbfile=new File("/sdcard/TheDataBaseFile");
        SQLiteDatabase db=SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);
        return db;
    }
}

    }
```